# How to convert canvas to image?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am converting the whole page into canvas, now I want to convert it into an image that I can download:

```
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas).setAttribute("id", "canvas");
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
      document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
    }
  });
```

That works but I get this error in console and the image isn't created

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: base64 encode the image data  -> `img`

Comment: @EricSo could you please elaborate it more into an answer based on the code above?

Comment: I think you are trying to capture the current screen by the library `html2canvas` then put that in a image tag right? because the browser defined the captured image as local domain. for security reason the browser does not allow you use the `toDataURL` API to export the image.

Comment: @EricSo it is exactly what I am doing, how can i resolve that?

Comment: I don't think you can resolve it. It is because of security reason. For example a hacker use this kind of javascript to get content of your private email.

Comment: @EricSo so i cannot convert elements into canvas and create an image out of it to be able to download it or send it to a pdf? Meaning canvas to pdf it cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="download" 
  onclick="var download = document.getElementById('download');
  download.href = document.getElementById('canvasElementId').toDataURL();
  download.download='imageName.png'">
Save Canvas Image</a>
```

You had all that excess stuff you didn't need and it would generate an image that you have to do an extra step by right clicking and saving. This is way easier and works better.

If it has an error saying that "tainted canvases can't be exported", then you could remove the taint if it doesn't work and if you can be able to with your application.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Answer (score -1):

If you can post the image data to a php script, it is very simple.

Posting data to php:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$.post("https://path-to-your-script/capture.php", {image: imgData},
    function(data) {
        console.log('posted');
});
```

Collecting data in php script:

*capture.php*

```
$data = $_POST['image'];

// remove "data:image/png;base64," from image data.
$data = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $data);

// save to file
file_put_contents("/tmp/image.png", base64_decode($data));
```